# Asp.net core mvc identity

Tags: model-view-controller, identity, razor-pages

I decided to build application with mvc pattern using identity for authentication. But when I scaffold identity, it automatically adds razor pages in my mvc project. I didn't found in microsoft docs how to scaffold identity for mvc. So I wanted to ask is it a good practise to leave razor pages in mvc project just for authentication purposes ?

Comment: Nope, only if you're going to use them

Comment: The scaffolder only outputs Razor Pages because that is the recommended way to generate UI on the server in .NET Core/5. MVC controllers should only be used to build APIs.